# Reed Switch False Activations

Tags: filter

I have a DIY weather station connected to a Davis Rain Collector (6463). The device is connected to the mains in my barn (separate 100 amp leg from the house). On that same mains I have 2 high powered electric fence chargers. The fence chargers cause the circuit for the rain collected to be activated falsely. The rain collector uses a simple magnetic reed switch. My circuit for detecting a tip in the bucket is below (pin 3 connects to the reed switch on the rain collector). If I disconnect the fence chargers then everything works fine.

My question is how can I filter out the pulses from the fence chargers?

[image: circuit]

Comment: How long are the wires?   Using a smaller pulling resistor (1K or even 470 ohms) might help.  Or you could run actual current through the sensor (and an appropriate series resistor) to power the LED side of an optocoupler.  Try to keep the wire runs short, for example put the counting electronics closer to the sensor.  Why does the weather station even need to be on the barn and not the house?

Comment: thanks. there is extra wire so i'll definitely shorten that up and see if that helps. there is current running to one side of the reed switch. the +5V on pin 2 goes to the reed switch.

Comment: how long is it?

Comment: you have electric-field coupling thru the air??? increase the capacitance on the node that gets upset. Use 1,000pF  (0.001uF) or 10,000pf (0.01 uF)

Comment: @analogsystemsrf where in my circuit would i put the capacitor? between the pull down resistor and ground? between the line to D11 and the pull down?

Answer (score 0):

Software de-glitcing should fix it, the rain catcher should produce much longer pulses than the fence chargers make. so just ignore the short pulses.

if you want to make your circuit immune to noise that's a harder task.

maybe something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fStiRW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

or something with common-mode noise rejection,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flvMAg.png)</sup>

Comment: i agree that using software is the best "fix" for this. thanks for the suggestion. i wrote a test to measure the pulse width with no rain and just the fence charger running. looks like nearly all the fence pulses are about 14 microseconds. there are some fence pulses that are measured at 1300 milliseconds. this happens frequently but i can easily filter those out too. i'll use a heuristic that discards the very fast and the very long pulses. should work.

Comment: ok, i implemented the software filter and it seems to be working well. my only concern is with the long fence pulses. i haven't measured how long and actual bucket tip in the pluviometer takes, but if that duration conflicts with the long fence pulses i'll have a problem.

Comment: after monitoring the actual pulse widths for a day i can see that software filtering is not possible. the pulse widths for the fence pulses are too erratic and there is no deterministic range to filter out.